# How to register users with Google Account on android app

Tags: android, mysql, google-play-services, google-oauth

So, I'm creating an android app, and along with my standard registration method, I'd like to allow users to register using their Google account. I've seen a lot of information on "Log in with Google+" as well as OAuth implementations. However, I still haven't seen anything that really touches on just authenticating a user and allowing them to register for an application using their Google account, and then later log in using the same account, referencing my local copy of the user account record in my database. Essentially, what I want to do is:

- Allow user to register an account using their Google account, which I assume would pull basic information such as name and email address, which I could use to create a local db record
- When the user registers with their Google account, tie that registration or token id to the actual record in my database. Something that allows me to identify that user/record with a Google Account
- When that user decides to login with Google, search for an existing association (access/token id) and log them in with that information (assuming it's still valid) and at 
  the same time pull their local account information (for example, submitted reviews for a movie review application) that is tied to that Google Account.

I hope I've explained what I'm trying to accomplish, but if it still sounds a bit vague let me know and I'll try to explain more. Any help is greatly appreciated. I obviously don't expect anyone to code this for me, just to point me in the right direction, or just tell me that what I'm trying to do is a horrible idea. Either way, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of Google accounts on the machine and use that as a key (see AccountManager), but how do you prevent someone from faking a connection to your server using someone else account ? 'Just' authenticating is complicated if you want 1/ to avoid security flaws and 2/ to avoid to handle the user password.
So OAuth is the way to go: the phone will generate an access token (after the user is prompted to allow your application to access his account), this token can be sent to your server (https), then your server can check against google servers that the token is valid and get back a unique id for the user.
See http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. So, let's assume I implement this solution the OAuth way using GoogleAuthUtil. From what I've read, this doesn't involve a challenge prompt since a Client Id will be created for both web and android, and instead Google will just hand me a token. My question is, how do I use this for registration? I'm aware that there is a JSON payload with basic information, but how do I tie this token and information to a record in my db so that I can, when a user decides to log in with Google, check to see if they're association exists and load their local info.

Comment: Essentially, when a person registers and logs in using Google, I want to have an associated ID in my db to make use of when making calls to a RESTful web service.

Comment: Where is your DB ? On a server ? In the terminal ?

Comment: A MySQL db on a server.

Comment: So each time the app connects to your server, you'll get a token and you'll have to connect to a google API (e.g. 'plus API' and get 'me') to ensure is it valid and convert it to an ID (the user email should be good). You can also generate a session ID and return it to the android app for further authentication if you don't want to connect to Google for each connection from the app.

Comment: You can also consider using an App Engine server to handle the server authentication, as it's a Google product the communication wih the android device will be easy. From there you can connect to your server, or even do all your stuff on app engine (they have mysql databases and an efficient but private datastore, they support Java, python and php, and it's free for small apps).

Comment: A bit late on selecting your answer, but you definitely pushed me in the right direction, all good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should start by reading some tutorials on how to achieve the registration.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

and

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

Maybe for the handling of the database you should use a content provider:

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/

or

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

the rest is just coding and some hard work. Hope i addressed you problem.